# Is there a way to get SAS to only print the first 10 rows of a frequency table?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sas, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm using proc freq in a Jupyter notebook but I don't want all the rows in the resulting frequency table to be displayed, only the first 10. I tried using (obs=10) but that just prints a frequency table using the first 10 observations in the data, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly from PROC FREQ.  You can do it in two steps:

1. PROC FREQ, but don't print the output; instead, send it to a table with OUT=
2. PROC PRINT or PROC REPORT the table, using OBS= to limit it.

One example:

```
proc freq data=sashelp.cars;
tables make;
run;
```

becomes

```
proc freq data=sashelp.cars noprint;
tables make/out=tbl_make;
run;

proc print data=tbl_make(obs=10) noobs;
run;
```

One highly recommended option is to add the `order=freq` option to the proc freq statement as usually the higher frequencies are what you're interested in.

Comment: Note that there are more ways than this, but this is the simplest.  In particular, with PROC DOCUMENT you could do some interesting things, or if you used SASPY in jupyter (you probably already have that set up I'm guessing) you could use python to call the PROC FREQ and then use python's natural methods for subsetting the output.